# Desktop w/Blu-Ray in one room, DLNA-compatible TV in another — streaming?

Tags: video-streaming, blu-ray, dlna

My TV supports DLNA streaming. I have a Blu-Ray drive in my desktop computer and I'd like to stream Blu-Ray movies directly to my TV. Is this even possible, and if so, does any Blu-Ray software support outbound DLNA streaming? If not, what are some other options? The desktop is in another room, and I don't want to buy another Blu-Ray player just for the TV.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ok
2. UScreenCapture, OK. Audio, on one computer, I choose SoundMax HD Audio, on another one, I choose default. Not sure what device it is using. You need try, default or ‘vitual-audio-capturer’?
3. Yes. But you have options to configure. For example, for video device, you can set frame rate. The higher rate it is, the more data captured. 24p movie is about 25 (frames per second), some people use 30. But it also takes more computer resources and network bandwidth when streaming. You could make lower if needed, such as 12. But the picture jumps if it is too low.
4. No. Click next.
5. selected ‘http’, and you clicked “ADD”, right? and put the path /test.flv. Can you TV play flash videos?

   - Again, it is important to select a proper file format and transcoding. But you can do a lot testing.
   - Check “Activate Transcoding”, profile-> select one from the list or create a new one if needed, e.g. “video – H.264 + AAC (MP4)”.
     “edit selected profile”->video codec->Codec: H-264, Bitrate (e.g. 2048) and Frame rate (same as what you set for capture device). 
     The larger bitrate you choose, the more date generated, again you need test to optimize.
   - Choose a value that delivers decent picture quality and streaming quality; 
     -> Audio codec->Codec: MPEG 4 Audio (AAC), bitrate: e.g. 128, channels: 2, sample rate: e.g. 44100.
   - But I always make it lower, since it’s not as important as pictures.
     H.264 delivers the best quality.
     You could try other codecs. You need test to get the best video quality and network speed.

6.You should see something like:  :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=4096,fps=25,scale=0,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{dst=:8080/test.flv} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep

The link is :8080/test.flv, where localhost is ignored. You could add it: dst=127.0.0.1:8080/test.flv

To test the link, it’s better to test with vlc or other media players first.
Open another vlc session, Media->Open network stream-> URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/flv.test (localhost could ignored).

- Another test is optional: stream to a file, using the codecs you are using, then add the file to TVersity and play one TV.
- To add the URL to TVersity library: TVersity->Library->Internet Media->Internet Video->Add data->Video URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/test.flv

Try TVersity with other internet videos first, and make sure URL videos work. I’m using 1.9.3. I tried 1.9.6(?) last time and got problems.

Check VLC and TVersity documentations for basic settings.